# Munchausen syndrome by proxy, caregiver and care receiver relation

Tags: mental-health, diagnostics

Does Munchausen Syndrome by Proxy only apply to a parent (caregiver) and his/her child (care receiver)? Or does it apply to any relation between a caregiver and a care receiver with that kind of behavioural pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Munchausen by proxy has been diagnosed for caregiver/care receiver relationships that were not parent / child. [Munchausen by adult proxy](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jhm.2268/abstract)  is an article reviewing 13 cases found in the medical literature where the care receiver in the relationship was an adult. Not all of the perpetrators were parents.

> The perpetrator was the victim's mother in 3 cases, **wife** in 2 cases, son in 2 cases, and daughter, granddaughter, **husband**, companion, boyfriend, or **prison cellmate** in 1 case each. Five (38%) worked in healthcare.

From [Munchausen Syndrome by Proxy :An Adult Dyad](http://www.psychosomaticsjournal.com/article/S0033-3182(11)00210-6/abstract#/article/S0033-3182(11)00210-6/fulltext)

> Although well-documented in the child and adolescent literature, few case reports document MSBP with an adult proxy

The majority of cases seem to be underage children and parents (usually mothers), though.